# assigning char by char to c++ string

Tags: c++, string

I have a text file in which the data is stored in following format:-

```
aabb:aabb
aacc:aacc
aadd:aadd
bbdd:bbdd
bbaa:bbaa
```

I am reading from the file line by line and trying to separate the words on either side of ':'. I am taking each line into a string line. I am assigning the word left to ':', char by char in the string w and the word right to ':', char by char to string m. But the problem is the the string w and m become empty after both the loops are executed. Why are string w and m empty?

```
int flag;
string line, w, m;
ifstream fin;
fin.open("files/file2.txt",ios::in);
if (fin.is_open()) {
    while (getline(fin,line)) {
        for (int i=0; i<line.length(); i++) {
            if (line[i] == ':') {
                flag = i+1;
                break;
            } else
                w[i] = line[i];
        }
        for(int i=flag,k=1; i<line.length(); i++,k++) {
            m[k] = line[i];
        }
        cout<<w<<'\n';
        cout<<m<<'\n';
    }
    fin.close();
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why are string w and m empty?

Comment: Try `w += line[i];` and `m += line[i];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are assigning characters to positions of `m` and `w` that do not exist yet: both strings are initially empty, so applying `[]` to them causes undefined behavior.

Since you are adding characters to the end of your strings, use `append` instead of `[]`:

```
w.append(1, line[i]);
...
m.append(1, line[i]);
```

or `+=`:

```
w += line[i];
...
m += line[i];
```